# Create new column with categorical variables based on date range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

If I have a data from like this with lets day timeseries dates for a year (2019) -

```
datetime
0   15.02.19 13:00
1   15.02.19 14:00
2   15.02.19 15:00
3   15.02.19 16:00
4   15.02.19 17:00
```

And I want to create a new column which has the value 'school holiday' if my datetime is within a range (school holiday dates from 2019) and 'term time' otherwise how would I approach this in the most efficient way possible? The resultant dataframe should look something like this-

```
datetime    school holiday
0   15.02.19 13:00  Term time
1   15.02.19 14:00  Term time
2   15.02.19 15:00  Term time
3   15.02.19 16:00  Term time
4   15.02.19 17:00  School Holiday
```

My thoughts were that I would take the school holiday dates which would be something like this:

```
Autumn Half Term Holidays   21 Oct 2019 - 25 Oct 2019
Winter Holidays             23 Dec 2019 - 3 Jan 2020
etc...
```

And make a dictionary with these dates, then somehow use lamba apply? Essentially the function should be - if datetime == holiday_range: 'school holiday' else: 'Term time'.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful:

```
holidays = {'Autumn Half Term Holidays': ('16 Feb 2019', '25 Feb 2019')}
holidays_map = {date.date(): holiday for holiday, dates in holidays.items() for date in pd.date_range(*dates)}

df['holiday'] = df['datetime'].dt.date.map(holidays_map).fillna('Term time')

df

             datetime                    holiday
0 2019-02-15 13:00:00                  Term time
1 2019-02-15 14:00:00                  Term time
2 2019-02-15 15:00:00                  Term time
3 2019-02-15 16:00:00                  Term time
4 2019-02-16 17:00:00  Autumn Half Term Holidays
```

Comment: Ooo this is smart (and very efficient) since the holidays likely wont have a time component :D +1

Comment: @ALollz how would I build the dictionary so that instead of mapping each date range to a unique holiday like ' Autumn Half Term Holidays', I mapped all of my holidays to one category, ie. 'school holiday' ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You likely have more rows in your DataFrame than unique Holidays. For problems like this you'll probably need to loop somewhere, so better to loop over the smaller number of Holidays

Convert your dates to `datetime` dtype and let's store the Holidays in a separate DataFrame, again with a `datetime` dtype

```
import pandas as pd
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Holiday': ['Autumn Half Term Holidays', 'Winter Holidays'],
                    'start': pd.to_datetime(['2019-10-21', '2019-12-23']),
                    'end': pd.to_datetime(['2019-10-25', '2020-01-03'])})
```

---

Now to determine if something is a holiday, we check if the datetime is between **any** of the periods. The map just gets your labels instead of True/False. I added a row to your example given your holidays just to illustrate that it works.

```
df['holiday'] = (pd.concat([df['datetime'].between(start, end) for start,end in zip(df2.start, df2.end)], 1)
                   .any(1)
                   .map({True: 'School Holiday', False: 'Term time'}))

             datetime         holiday
0 2020-01-01 01:00:00  School Holiday
1 2019-02-15 13:00:00       Term time
2 2019-02-15 14:00:00       Term time
3 2019-02-15 15:00:00       Term time
4 2019-02-15 16:00:00       Term time
5 2019-02-15 17:00:00       Term time
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just perfectly although I feel for a large dataset zipa's solution may be faster?

Comment: @ojp yes that solution is going to be fast. This wont be too bad so long as the holidays aren't too numerous. Though if you had holidays (or timespans) with time components that were like '2019-12-01 14:00:00 - 2019-12-23 16:45:00' it would be difficult to generalize that solution. Still always best to use the best solution for the problem, which is zipa's :D

Comment: epic, I will keep your solution in the back pocket for when that problem arises then!